# Como mover o mouse automaticamente, de maneira realista, utilizando Python?

Tags: python, eventos-do-mouse, winapi

Como fazer o mouse mover-se automaticamente, de maneira realista, utilizando Python?

Consegui encontrar e alterar um código que me produz um movimento em formato de "V" na tela. No entanto, gostaria de mover o mouse utilizando movimentos não lineares.

Encontrei algumas ideias interessantes:

1. [Algoritmo para imitar o movimento do mouse como um humano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034181/algorithm-to-emulate-mouse-movement-as-a-human-does)
2. [Movendo o mouse de maneira realista usando C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913646/c-sharp-moving-the-mouse-around-realistically)
3. Movendo o mouse de maneira realista utilizando uma [Spline](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline) de [Interpolação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpola%C3%A7%C3%A3o) ou de [Aproximação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aproxima%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Estou enfrentando dificuldades na hora de incorporar a parte matemática da não-linearidade do movimento no meu código.

**Código:**

```
import sys
import time
import win32api

if (len(sys.argv) < 4):
    print "Como utilizar: python mousemove.py dx dy speed"
    sys.exit()

current = win32api.GetCursorPos()
cx = sx = current[0]
cy = sy = current[1]

mx = int(sys.argv[1])
my = int(sys.argv[2])
vx = vy = int(sys.argv[3])

print "Movendo", mx, my, "com", vx, "pixels por segundo"
print "Pressione 'q' para sair"

last = time.time()

while(True):
    if win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(ord('Q')):
        sys.exit()

    current = time.time()
    tick = current - last
    last = current

    if mx > 0:
        cx += vx * tick;
        if cx > mx + sx or cx < sx:
            vx = -vx;
            cx = max( sx, min( mx + sx, cx ) )
    if( my > 0 ):
        cy += vy * tick;
        if cy > my + sy or cy < sy:
            vy = -vy;
            cy = max( sy, min( my + sy, cy ) )

    win32api.SetCursorPos((int(cx),int(cy)))
    time.sleep(0.001)
```

**Trecho matemático que desenha um V:**

```
if mx > 0:
    cx += vx * tick;
    if cx > mx + sx or cx < sx:
        vx = -vx;
        cx = max( sx, min( mx + sx, cx ) )
if( my > 0 ):
    cy += vy * tick;
    if cy > my + sy or cy < sy:
        vy = -vy;
        cy = max( sy, min( my + sy, cy ) )
```

**Pergunta:**

Como devo definir as condições para incorporar uma certa aleatoriedade (não-linearidade) no movimento do cursor do mouse?

Answer (score 4):

Bem interessante o problema. Acredito que uma técnica boa para aprimorar seria utilizar os conceitos já estudados em UX (*User Experience*). Por exemplo, como citado no [Google Material](https://material.io/), você pode utilizar os movimentos **Arc Upward** ou **Arc Downward**, verificando a diferença de posições inicial e final desejadas.

Se a posição final do mouse estiver acima da posição inicial, utilize o movimento arc upward.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se a posição final do mouse estiver abaixo da posição inicial, utilize o movimento arc downward.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os movimentos parecem muito mais naturais que o linear.

> **Nota**: você pode ler um pouco da matemática [aqui](https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/concave-up-down-convex.html). Acredito que a implementação das equações não é complexa. Tentarei fazer em breve e, se der certo, edito a resposta com os códigos.